# Error in the log that the bucket size must be a power of 2 in Couchbase .Net 1.2 client

Tags: couchbase

I'm using Couchbase server 2.0 beta and trying to push up JSON documents and failing.  When checking the client log I found that I was getting an Exception...

> 2012-11-06 12:02:29,812 [22] ERROR Couchbase.CouchbasePool [(null)]
>   <(null)> - Failed to initialize the pool. System.ArgumentException:
>   bucket count must be a power of 2!    at
>   Enyim.Caching.Memcached.VBucketNodeLocator..ctor(String hashAlgorithm,
>   VBucket[] buckets)    at
>   Couchbase.CouchbasePool.InitVBucket(ClusterConfig config,
>   ISaslAuthenticationProvider auth)    at
>   Couchbase.CouchbasePool.ReconfigurePool(ClusterConfig config)

I'm not sure whats going on, can anyone shed some light?  I tried changing the bucket size to 2048 with no luck.

Comment: That error message is actually a little misleading, it's referring to VBuckets, not actual item buckets.  What version of the .NET client are you using?  The error implies that there's a problem with the config coming from the server being read by the client...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install couchbase server on windows 8? I was having this exact same issue and installing it in a windows server VM resolved it although there is a reported workaround,

See:
http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-6395